# SQL build fails in azure dev ops pipelines when selecting Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse as the target platform in Visual Studio

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-synapse

SQL build fails in azure dev ops pipelines when selecting Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse as the target platform in Visual Studio 2019

It succeeds when i change the target platform to Microsoft Azure SQL database, but fails when i change it to SQL data warehouse, which i the one that i want.

The MSBuild task is the one that fails in the ADO pipelines, with an error that says ;msbuild.exe exited with code 1; I've tried with a VSBuild task, but also get the same result

Does anyone know why is that?

Comment: Here is a [blog](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5985/continuous-database-deployments-with-azure-devops/) you can refer to ,hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I already have the exact same workflow as in the blog and works as expected. It works because the blog is using "Azure SQL Database" as the target platform and not "Azure SQL **DataWareHouse** (as shown in the release pipeline). The problem comes in when you want to setup continous deployment for a Azure SQL Data Warehouse.